# Subversion searching all revisions of the whole repository for text

Tags: svn, search, repository

Title says all,
I got a string, e.g. "Foo", and I want to search my whole repository file contents, and all the revisions (diffs) made to it since the start of time for that String.
So basically I want to know whether this string "Foo" was ever part of my source code.

I noticed that there are some hacky solutions for searching subversion all revisions, one file at a time, but that won't really do it for me.

I also found this http://svnquery.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=o0dpdE
which seems like a solution. Any alternatives/thoughts?

Comment: "revisions ... for that String" is unclear defunition. There may this string will appear - in commit-message, filename|path or inside diff as *content of change*?

Comment: I made it a bit more clear, I want to know if that String was ever in the past part of my source code, and if that's the case see that revision (diff) that altered it

Comment: I want to see the whole file that the text belonged to when it belonged in the source code. So if "Foo" was in a file Test.java 2 years ago, I want to see the whole "Test.java" file as it was 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN core in historical-search|data-mining is rather weak, but I can suggest at least 2 pure SVN-solutions

- [svnrevgrep](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/05/22/grep-through-code-history-with-git-mercurial-or-svn/) (Python, has some limitations, mentioned in comments)
- [svngrep](http://atastypixel.com/blog/searching-through-subversion-history/) (Bash+Perl+grep, not Windows-friendly)

and mentioned by Eli "foreign SCM" method

> if you’re using Mercurial or Git, you’re lucky because both provide built-in methods for doing this.

because installing Mercurial (*Mercurial after SVN* and *Mercurial in general* is the natural way, Git - isn't) and adding HGSubversion and cloning repo will require just small amount of time, but you get power tools for exploring and extracting data from your SVN-repo *forever*

HG-example (based on existing on deck repos)

```
> hg grep --all load_theme_textdomain *.php
functions.php:2:-:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
functions.php:2:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
functions.php:1:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
```

String was added in changeset 1 (second ":"-separated field) and edited in changeset 2 (- and + actions in the same revision)